# Do android support midi programming?

Tags: android, html, audio, midi

I've been trying to make a simple virtual piano for android, and tried a several bunch of diferent tools, by example the jfugue port and the openfl midi library.

But I haven't been able to make a simple basic hello world playing a midi file.

It seems there's no MIDI api.

Even something as playing this html5 virtual piano doesn't work
http://mudcu.be/piano/
The page doesn't load the midi both in my phone (android 10) and my tablet (android 15) neither I can play the keys.

I just want to know if programming audio midi mobile software is possible and if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [android.media.midi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html) package has only been added in API 23 or Android 6.0 as per the [API Overview page](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#audio). Android 6.0 is currently in [Developer Preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html) in preparation of its final release in Q3 2015.

Comment: Can I use the minimal sdk and set it to 10 and still be able to use the API 23? I'd really love if I can support my phone with it.

Comment: Alas, as with most hardware related APIs, using the midi APIs would require an API 23 device.